# Blender 3.0 Error Msg: "No Valid Selected Objects" Can't bake

Tags: error

[image]I've tried to find a solution to no avail, anybody?

I checked the 'Selected Active" box as well - didn't help.

Checked all the the 'disable' icons, especially the camera icon, in the Scene Collection window on & off - doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: Since the only object selected in the outliner is the camera (camera.001) and you can't 'bake' a camera... Select the object you're trying to bake, either in the outliner or the 3D view and try again!

Comment: Thanks, didn't work... too many errors to mention, however, the image 'rendered' is exactly what I'm after, just can't 'bake it!'

Comment: I actually unchecked "selected to active" and it worked for me. No idea why.